# How do I animate ::after elements width from right to left?

Tags: html, css, animation, flip

I've got a button which uses the ::after pseudo to fill the background. Currently it fills from left to right which makes sense as the width goes from 0 to 100%. However, i'm wanting it to flip the way it fills.

```css
a.project--link {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(red, .2);
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  z-index: 1;
  }
  a.project--link:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(red, .7);
    transform: scale(1.02);
    transition: all .2s ease;
  }
  a.project--link::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
  }

a.project--link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="project--link">View Project</a>
```

It would be a huge help if anyone can shed some light on how to flip the animation.

Comment: Can you post CSS please, and your markup too, so we have a working demo?

Comment: Sure, I'll quickly add it to codepen

Comment: Patrick, ideally you should put your code in the post itself, not a third party site.

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: scaleX()` instead of `width` and use `transform-origin` to control the direction.

```css
a.project--link {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(red, .2);
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

a.project--link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(red, .7);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

a.project--link::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

a.project--link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="project--link">View Project</a>
```

Comment: @PatrickWhitehouse ah thanks for your markup. updated my answer

Comment: Cheers! Could you possibly give me an explanation as to why it doesn't work with width?

Comment: @PatrickWhitehouse because transform-origin applies to the `transform` property...

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot.